# Querying in CloudCode returns empty objects

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I've got a problem with configuring job in parse.com

Part of my code

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
var query = new Parse.Query('Voucher');
query.find({
  success: function(a){console.log(a)}
});
```

This code prints a list of empty objects. Length of this list is at should be.